# ftp list file name via bash

Tags: bash, ftp

I need to extract the list of files of a ftp server (just the filename)

I placed all the **commands** in a txt file and call it with

```
ftp -ivn < ftp.command > ls.txt
```

(content of ftp.command)

```
open 192.168.43.12
user user1 pasw1
ls
```

so, ls.txt contains

```
drwxr-xr-x    4 1000     100          4096 Dec 05 05:09 FILE1
drwxrwxrwx    2 1000     100          4096 Dec 11 09:38 FILE3
drwxrwxrwx    2 1000     100          4096 Dec 05 09:11 FILE2
```

I need to extract

```
FILE1
FILE2
FILE3
```

How can I parse the output of ls?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To retrieve just a list of file names, use `nlist` instead of `ls`.

On the FTP protocol level, the command is `NLST`.

There may still be output which you do not want to store (in my simple `ftp` client, the status messages are included).

FTP clients and servers differ a lot in implementation details, but the protocol provides this facility precisely so that you don't have to do any additional parsing on the file name list you receive.

Comment: `ls -1` is a nice way to list just filenames, if it's supported by the FTP server.

Comment: That's silly. Use the dedicated FTP command instead of commands which depend on the server's local operating system. Also, [using `ls` in scripts is discouraged on Unix-like systems](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), too.

Comment: It depends on your point of view. IMO, your response is silly. `nlist` itself is not a "dedicated FTP command", but an abstration by the operating system, which isn't always available. I just tried it on one server, and got `Invalid command.` I stand over my comment - it may come in nice and handy for some users, depending on their specific use case.

Comment: Your `ftp` client probably calls the command something else. See if you can send bare FTP protocol-level commands (try `quote` maybe) and/or consult your FTP client's documentation or online help. Sometimes they are so "user friendly" that you can't tell what a command actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
grep -oE '[^ ]+$' ls.txt
```

Comment: This will obviously fail spectacularly if a file name contains a space. It will probably also fail if a file name contains a control character and the `ftp` server displays it as `?` or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there are lot of ways to do that, here are few:

1. Instead of `ls` use `ls whateveryouwant | xargs -n 1 basename`
2. If you know the path, then `ls /path/*.txt | sed -r 's/^.+\///'`
3. `ls -1 *.txt`